# How can evaluating the limit of function give a different result after rationalizing it?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

One of the examples in *Calculus: A complete course* is finding $\lim_{x\to \infty}  (\sqrt{x^2+x}-x)$. At first it seems to produce a meningless $\infty-\infty$, but by rationalizing it we eventually come up with $1\over2$. What I don't understand is how it is possible to derive different results depending on the form of the function, since from my understanding two equivalent functions should yield the same result.

Comment: An indeterminate form simply means that we have to do more work to figure out what (if anything) the limit is. It is not, in itself, a result--rather, it is the lack of a result.

Comment: The very expression  $\infty-\infty$ produces confusion, and should be avoided. If we imagine $x$ to be very large, it is clear that $\sqrt{x^2+x}$ (and $x$) are very large, but the behaviour of their difference is not obvious. Writing the expression in an equivalent form makes the behaviour for large $x$ clear. As an *analogy*, if we have a complicated expression $E(x)$, it may not be clear for what $x$ we have $E(x)=0$. Algebraic manipulation of $E(x)$ may make the roots accessible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "non-result" of $\infty - \infty$ upon initial substitution is one of the many [indeterminate forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms).  Obtaining an [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) of a limit is not at all a result:  it tells us only that we have to do more work to figure out if and/or what the limit actually is.

So obtaining an indeterminate form, like you found, isn't really meaningless, nor is it a result: it tells us our work has just begun.

Rationalizing the function, as you did in this case, is one technique to help us to actually evaluate a limit, if it exists, in order to determine what the result actually is.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @amWhy: What nice feedback! +1

Answer (score 4):

As you said, $\infty-\infty$ is meaningless, hence there's no contradiction, the results are not different; in first approach you just fail to present it in a meaningfull way.